# gae bulkloader won't parse key name on import?

Tags: google-app-engine

in the default bulkloader.yaml it said this:

```
#    - Check that __key__ property is what you want. Its value will become
#      the key name on import, and on export the value will be the Key
#      object. If you would like automatic key generation on import and
#      omitting the key on export, you can remove the entire __key__
#      property from the property map.
```

so I assume the default implementation:

```
- property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

should import the key column in my csv file into the datastore with no problem. However it appear to do nothing. (other columns were parsed fine though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right on that the default implement was enough. No import_transform was needed. I couldn't parse key value because the first column in the csv file (which contained the keys) could never be parsed no matter which field it contains. Simply place a dummy column as the first column fixed the problem.

@Calvin, sorry I didn't validate your answer sooner.

Answer (score 2):

You need an import_transform to get the key into the datastore.  The export transform is for writing out to the csv file.

I don't think there's a built-in transform method to turn a string back into a key.

I wrote two helper functions for dealing with exporting and importing keys:
[key_to_reverse_str (export) and reverse_str_to_key (import)](http://code.google.com/p/bulkloader-gdata-connector/source/browse/bulk_helper.py)
The idea was to keep the value human readable on exporting, but keep all data needed for import. They might be useful for you.